# Jenkins Builds But Still Shows as Failed

Tags: jenkins, gradle, mercurial, tomcat7

I have Jenkins 2.55 running on Tomcat7 with an Ubuntu 16.04 OS. Three of my jobs are running. They all appear to build just fine, but for some odd reason I get the red orb and storm clouds indicating failure.

I checked Tomcat logs and when I check build history, all I get is a Mercurial revision string with no error. Not sure where to go from here to see why I am getting this possible false positive.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to print the currentBuild status between your steps to narrow down your problem. When you identified the step which sets the build to failed, split up this step in more steps until you got the operation which lets the build fail.

It depends on your job type how to narrow down.

For Pipeline Jobs you can print the currentBuild result like this (and you don't have to do any splitting, you can print the currentBuild result everywhere):

```
node("master") {
    stage("sometest") {
        echo "${currentBuild.result}"
    }
}
```

For the old world you can print the currentBuild result with a groovy system script.You have to install the groovy plugin for this and add a "Execute system Groovy script":

```
import hudson.model.*

def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
println "${build.getResult()}"
```